# Can I do return after return in if statement? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can we use `return` followed by another `return` in `Javascript`?

Like this:

```
if(a==b){
   return (if(a==c){
               return a;
           });
}
```

So it is like: if `a` is equal `b`, it will return to another `if` statement and this `if` statement will compare `a` and `c`, if they are equal, then return `a`, this is just an example, no specific meaning, but wondering if cascaded `return` even works. Thank you!

Comment: Once you return, that's it; you've returned. Do you understand what `return` does?

Comment: Have you tried using this (kind of) code?

Comment: No, this won't work. Any code after a return statement will never be executed.

Comment: What is your intent in the above code?

Comment: Nope, try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ and see for yourself

Comment: The code will never execute at all since it's invalid. Simply running the code and looking at the developer console would tell you that.

Comment: what would you like to return?

Comment: Syntax errors aside, it's not clear to me what the meaning of the first `return` would be. *"return to another `if` statement"* what does that even mean?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do when `a==b` but `a!=c`?

Comment: This is just an example, with no meaning as I said, I am just wondering if a `return` can be followed by another `return` because logically, return will jump out with the statement after it, so the statement here is another `if` statement with another `return`. I dont even know how I come up with this example but this is just a curious question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single if statement.

```
if (a == b && a == c) {
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need both returns. I am not positive how this plays out, but it's not a good practice. It would be better to do:

```
if (a==b) {
  if (a==c) {
    return a;
  }
}
```

Edit: Or a more concise way...

```
if (a==b && a==c) {
  return a;
}
```

Comment: His code would either raise for trying to return a statement, or it would return a null value? Maybe? Can't remember how JS acts in this regard.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah that's what I'm unsure of, how far after return will it evaluate... Either way it's going to be throw some error.

Answer (score 0):

return statement stop the execution of a function and returns a value. You can't use two return statement in same bracket in a function but you can use a conjunction statement this way

`if (a === b && a === c){
    return a;}`